# The language name 'en-US' is invalid. (CS2038)

Tags: c#, .net, sharpdevelop

In an empty solution, I keep getting the warning - The language name 'en-US' is invalid. (CS2038).  I've tried everything.  But when I switch to C# 3.0, .NET 3.5 the warning goes away.  The warning goes away when I create a VB.NET Windows application solution as well.  Only when I create a c#5.0 NET 4.5 Windows Application Solution does this occur.  And I have to have 4.5 because of dependent libraries compiled against 4.5.

Has anyone else seen this?  It seems to be independent of #Develop.  Is there a config file or something for the .NET 4.5 framework C# that I'm missing?

Edited to add for clarification (from comments):

I've reduced it to no source code files at all. Strangely enough it does not do this on my Windows 7 machine, only on my Vista. Windows 7 being 64 bit and the Vista machine being 32. I'm sure it has something to do with that.

Comment: Does the error message point to any particular piece of code? What sort of app is this? (WPF, WinForms etc.)

Comment: No, it doesn't point to any line in code.  I've even removed all the files from the solution one at a time, building after each removal and I still get it every time.

Comment: It is just a basic Windows (WinForms) application.

Comment: Can you look at whatever files are left and see whether anything *does* specify en-US? (It does sound like this is a Sharpdevelop issue, so I may not be able to help much.)

Comment: en-US is nowhere in there, I even ran a find text in files through the entire solution folder (outside of Sharpdevelop, using Notepad++) and nothing.  If it is a Sharpdevelop issue, I don't see it.

Comment: How are you building it? Can you reproduce this without using Sharpdevelop *anywhere*?

Comment: can i send you the code, so i'll at least know i'm not crazy?

Comment: You should try to reduce it to such a minimal example that you can include it in the question, rather than mailing me.

Comment: I've reduced it to no source code files at all.  Strangely enough it does not do this on my Windows 7 machine, only on my Vista.  Windows 7 being 64 bit and the Vista machine being 32.  I'm sure it has something to do with that.

Comment: Okay, well there must be *a* file - if only a project file. Can you include that, and how you're building?

Comment: Please DO NOT repeat tags in question titles.

Comment: See also: [this thread on MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4723264f-192e-4fa7-9fd1-a58426d65502/csc-warning-cs2038-the-language-name-enus-is-invalid?forum=csharpgeneral).

Comment: Check for assembly: AssemblyCulture or assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage in the entire source code.

Comment: Ondrej, I hadn't realized about that, my apologies, I haven't been on here for a while so please overlook it.

Comment: Matt Johnson, thanks I'm checking that out.

Comment: I pretty much just gave up on this.  It isn't causing any real problems so far and I just don't have the time to keep worrying about it.

Comment: With SharpDevelop on Windows Vista 64 bit I'm getting the same warning **"The language name 'en-US' is invalid. (CS2038)"**.  The warning does not occur when I build the same solution from the command line using MsBuild.  I don't know why building from SharpDevelop would cause the issue.  I **[submitted the issue](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/issues/753)** to SharpDevelop.

Comment: I usually do not post "me too" comments, but given that this issue seems to come so out of nowhere, the question might need some more people confirming the observation: Indeed, I am seeing (almost) the same warning, using SharpDevelop on a German Windows Vista x32; **"The language name 'de-DE' is invalid. (CS2038)"**

Comment: Not sure enough to post this as an answer, but I've seen this problem on several systems, and it seems like it is related to MS Office in some way. On at least three occasions (across 2 different machines and 2 different Windows versions, 7 and 10), I have seen it start occurring after installing Office language packs -- and it's always the OS language that becomes "invalid", not the Office languages I added.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that the culture `en-US` was registered as a "custom culture" in Windows.

In PowerShell running as Administrator, you can execute the following to unregister the custom culture:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName sysglobl;
[System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder]::Unregister("en-US");
```

In the Windows Control Panel "Region" window, you can check the `*` that indicates custom culture. This is how it's supposed to look afterwards (see there's no longer any `*` in the `English (United States)` name):

[image]